# How to speed up magento 1.7 collections

Tags: performance, magento, search

I have a custom catalog search with this code for an array containing search strings:

```
$collection =    Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', $visibility);

        foreach($searchNames as $searchName){
            $collection->addAttributeToFilter(array(
                    array('attribute'=> 'name','like' => '%'.$searchName.'%'),
                    array('attribute'=> 'search_field','like' => '%'.$searchName.'%'),
                    array('attribute'=> 'sku','like' => '%'.$searchName.'%')));
        }
```

When i get ~6k results the search takes about 5 seconds. Is there a way to speed this up?
Perhaps there are some performance tweaks i didn't find yet.

I have already set indexes to these fields in the table catalog_product_flat, but there are no changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexes will not work in your query for `name`, `search_field` and `sku` attributes! Because your LIKE value begins with a wildcard (%), and indexes can only work if it starts with a constant. Your query will speed up if you remove that leading `%` from LIKE values.

I don't understand why you are using foreach?

Comment: I use foreach for multiple searchstrings. $searchNames is an array containing these strings.